# How to share Image from imageSwitcher in android

Tags: android, share, gallery, bitmapfactory, imageswitcher

How do I code to share current image that is in view (in the imageSwitcher) from gallery. I have an app that have multiple images in a gallery which after selected is then loaded into an imageSwitcher. So now I want to Share the image currently being viewed and sent using the Share Intent bringing up share Options window.

This is my code:
TextView drawableId;TextView stringCopy;

```
    int imgs[] =
            {
                    R.drawable.pg1,
                    R.drawable.pg2,

            };
    String imgs1[] =
        {
                "R.drawable.pg1",
                "R.drawable.pg2",
        };
    int imgs2[] =
            {
                    R.drawable.infinity_96_58uvb_pg1,
                    R.drawable.infinity_96_58uvb_pg2,

            };

    ImageSwitcher imgSwitcher, imageSwitcher2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drawableId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    stringCopy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    imgSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(imageSwitcher1);
    imgSwitcher.setFactory(this);

    final Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    gallery.setAdapter(new MainActivity.ImageAdapter(this));

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                                long id) {
            imgSwitcher.setImageResource(imgs2[position]);
            drawableId.setText(imgs1[position]+"");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, imgSwitcher + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            imgSwitcher.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            postPicture();
        }

        public boolean postPicture() {
            String a = drawableId.getText().toString();
            stringCopy.setText(a);

            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(a);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share image File"));

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

       });



    }
```

And here is my Error:

E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: R.drawable.pg1: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.mt_br.floatingactionbutton, PID: 13647
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.mt_br.floatingactionbutton.MainActivity$2.postPicture(MainActivity.java:112)
                      at com.example.mt_br.floatingactionbutton.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:101)

Answer (score 0):

I substituted this:

```
     public boolean postPicture() {

            int Position = gallery.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgs2[Position]);
```